# Can't change a text value after overriding the TEXT property in custom control

Tags: c#, custom-controls

I have custom textbox control (TextBoxExt) from syncfustion UI, the problem is that the textbox already has text string so I needed to empty that text string so I used the following code to make it empty:

```
public override string Text { get => base.Text; set => base.Text = value = ""; }
```

And I got it but when I try to edit the Text property by the properties panel I couldn't, I can write but after leaving the property field the value that I wrote be cleared.

What is the problem?

Comment: `set => base.Text = value = "";` This will empty the value every single time you try to change it in the UI, not just the one time you want to empty it. `value` contains the text value that you wrote, but here it will be erased again (`value = ""`).

Comment: There is no problem, your code does what you asked it to do: every time something tries to write a value in the Text, it writes "" instead. A simple Text = ""; in the constructor should empty out your textbox.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties) to learn more about properties.

Comment: @BG_Cw actually I added text="" to the constructor but still keep the default text!!

Comment: @AstridE. so what I should to do? I removed the = ""

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with Syncfusion UI, and I don't know how `TextBoxExt` works. But to increase the possibility that someone may be able to help you, I suggest you include more of your code; such as how `Text` is used in the `TextBoxExt` control. Also, elaborate on _when_ you want `Text` to be reset -- is it when you open the form, or everytime you enter that specific input field? To me, it's unclear _why_ there's text in the input field in the first place, unless you want to erase it everytime you enter the input field.